# Автопоиск в поле формы и автозаполнение остальных полей согласно выбору из результатов поиска если таковые имеются в БД

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Имеется несколько полей форм. Нужно осуществить поиск по одному из полей. В данном случае - по полю `phone` при наборе более, к примеру, 4-5 первых символов(чисел). Если в таблице есть такие записи, с неким префиксом введенным пользователем в поле ввода, то вывести первые 5 результатов и автоматически заполнить остальные поля при выбранному одному из результатов.

Вот код обработчика формы:

```
$zakaz = $_POST['zakaz'];
$tel= $_POST['phone'];
$kol= $_POST['kol'];
$segod = $_POST['segod'];
$avto = $_POST['avto'];
$stat = $_POST ['stat'];

$sql = "insert into zakaz_table (zakaz, phone, kol, datavremya, member, segod, avto, stat) values ('$zakaz', '$tel', '$kol', DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 0 HOUR), '$usrname', '$segod', '$avto', '$stat')";

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
/* Закрываем соединение */
$mess = " Заказ отправлен на обратку ";
//echo $sql;
header("location:index.php?mess=$mess");
```

Соответствеено, `zakaz` — это адрес клиента, а `phone` — телефон, остальные поля не нужны для автозаполнения.

Comment: Подойдет любой реализованный код, дальше я сам ухвачу суть

Comment: Смотрите в поиске https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA+%D1%81+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 Один из примеров реализации http://htmlweb.ru/ajax/example/city.php

Comment: @Visman, конечно ссылка на другой ресурс - это хорошо. Но если ресурс удалят -то к данной информации не будет доступа. Вы бы лучше оформили код, который указан в источнике, как ответ для общей пользы.

Comment: @RomanKozin, вы уже все оформили :Р И гугл надеюсь не удалят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотека `mysql_*` уже устаревшая. Используйте лучше `mysqli` или `PDO`.

Создайте скрипт обработчик следующим образом:

**PHP**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '1111', 'db_name'); // Можно без указания БД
       // $mysqli->select_db($dbname) - Если хотите работать с несколькими БД
$look = $mysqli->query("select * from table where `phone` like '{$_POST['phone']}%'");
    if ($look->num_rows){
        echo json_encode($look->fetch_array());
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'receiver.php',
  data: "phone=" + $('#phone').val(),
  success: function (response) { //Обработка ответа },
      $("#phone").rules("add", {
                required: true
                minlength: 4
                });
      });
```

Да, и событие `onkeyup` на поле `phone`. Или обрабатываете его сразу же с `jQuery`.

Надеюсь, что мой ответ Вам поможет.

И не забудьте защитить свой код от SQL и XSS инъекций как минимум.

Comment: Код, конечно, было бы хорошо привести такой, который не позволяет провести SQL-инъекцию. Или в ответе упомянуть об этом.

Comment: @Visman, надеюсь на то, что каждый кто начинает учить PHP, должен знать о таких опасностях как SQL-Inj и XSS как минимум

Comment: Зря надеетесь ;)

Comment: @Visman, :D Сам когда-то такой был) Но с опытом пришло)

Comment: @RomanKozin, поддерживаю Visman. В текущем виде ваш код **нельзя** использовать из-за уязвимости к SQL-инъекции.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, я дал просто пример кода. Как его защищать - это уже решение пользователя.

Comment: @RomanKozin, раз так, то стоит об этом хотя бы упомянуть в ответе.